# Help proving vector spaces given operation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this exercise that asks me to prove the set V=R is a vector space.

Operations are

$ x \oplus y = \sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3} $

and

$ c \otimes x = \sqrt[3]{c*x} $

I already proved all axioms until Distributive
I'm getting a bit confused here, do i have to consider $ \otimes $ and $ \oplus$ as operations always ? (except for under the root)

For example, can i do this ?

$   
 c \otimes (x + y)  = \\ \sqrt[3]{c*(x+y)} = \\ 
\sqrt[3]{c*x + c*y} $

As you see i used $\otimes$ and normal +

Or is this the right way ?

$    (c \otimes x) \oplus (c \otimes y) = \\ \sqrt[3]{c*x} \oplus \sqrt[3]{c*y} = \\ \sqrt[3]{(\sqrt[3]{c*x})^3 + (\sqrt[3]{c*y})^3} =
 \\ \sqrt[3]{c*x + c*y} $

---

AND

$ 
 c \otimes (x \oplus y)  =\\ \sqrt[3]{c*(x\oplus y)} = \\ 
\sqrt[3]{c*x \oplus c*y} \\ 
\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{(c*x)^3 + (c*y)^3}}$

---

In this case distribution seems not to work as  $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{(cx)^3 + (cy)^3}}$  is not equal to $\sqrt[3]{cx + cy}$

Can someone help me do distribution the right way ? Thank you

Comment: I think you wrote down the question incorrectly. The part $c \otimes x = \sqrt[3]{y*x}$ doesn't make sense. Perhaps you meant to write $c \otimes x = \sqrt[3]{c}\ x$?

Comment: As far as I can see the question is wrong even after correcting the definition of $c\otimes x$.

Comment: Original one is this [link] (https://i.imgur.com/ELhg5CI.png) Image

Comment: Ah allright, sorry, i saw i put x instead of c.

Comment: The cube root sign should also extend to only $c$, not until $x$.

Comment: I didn't notice that, that changes everything.

Answer (score 1):

You have copied the definition wrongly. The correct definition of $c \otimes x$ is $c \otimes x=(\sqrt [3] c)x$.

Comment: Ok i'm trying to solve now, i'll post updates

Comment: Here is how i solved [link] (https://i.imgur.com/aY9JHt8.png)

Comment: Fine, you are done!

Answer (score 0):

My solution after question correction

[image]